# Automated tool to remove symantec AV

Tags: anti-virus, symantec

I need a tool to automatically remove Symantec AV (~v10.0) from desktops when the uninstall password is not known or the install is corrupt. I know some AV products will do this for you if they can (Trend sometimes) but in other cases it would be great not to have to remove it manually since this is about 33 steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a set of scripts to do just this task. You can download them [Here](http://brokenhaze.com/downloads/KillSym.rar)

You have to into each of the batch files and edit them so that  matches your enviroment.

Let me know if you need more info or if you have issues. This script has been used on thousands of machines at my company.

Comment: Have to manually remove the Symantec AV add-in link from outlook but not a big deal.

Comment: Good to hear - ahh gotcha probably just another registry key on the plugin we disabled it out of the box so it wasn't an issue for me. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Symantec has a tool to do this that can be run on the local system nonav249.exe is available from Symantec support.  Works every time for me.