# Problems installing Symantec AntiVirus Corporate Edition 10.2 for Windows Vista

Tags: security, anti-virus, symantec

I'm having some problems installing [Symantec AntiVirus Corporate Edition 10.2 for Windows Vista](http://service1.symantec.com/SUPPORT/ent-security.nsf/docid/2006102615175748). My client requires this exact version.

The system on which I'm installing the software is recently purchased system (i.e. relatively "clean") that came with [Symantec Norton Internet Security 2009](http://www.symantec.com/norton/internet-security) preinstalled.

The system has a 64-bit AMD Athlon and it is running Microsoft Windows Vista 64 Home Premium Edition (again, preinstalled).

My plan was to uninstall the 2009 version and install the 10.2 corporate edition.

For my first attempt, I ran the Norton uninstall program that I found in the Norton folder. The uninstall program seemed to work properly. Next, I ran the corporate 10.2 installer, but I got an error dialog saying:

```
Symantec Antivirus install FAILED!
Please reboot and try again.
note: You may need to run NONAV249.exe if the reinstall fails
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [iparelan.com](http://iparelan.com/NortonError.png))</sub>

Suspecting that the 2009 uninstall wasn't clean, I ran the [Norton Removal Tool](http://service1.symantec.com/Support/tsgeninfo.nsf/docid/2005033108162039). Then I tried to install the corporate 10.2 version again, but I got the exact same error.

I'm pretty sure that my system meets the [system requirements](http://service1.symantec.com/support/ent-security.nsf/docid/2006103013172348) for Corporate Edition 10.2.

It seems that at least [one other person](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/unable-install-corporate-edition-sav102) has had this same problem.

**Any thoughts on how to complete this installation of Corporate Edition 10.2? What is `NONAV249.exe`?**

Comment: Info on NONAV249.exe: http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/removal-sav-10x-nonav-tool

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the client install package for Vista? If I remember correctly from about a year ago, I had to specify the client install location and point it to where the Vista client was. I don't remember if I had to download it separately, but I believe I did.

Comment: My installer does not ask for the client location (or it hasn't gotten that far yet!)

Comment: Right, it's not going to. If I remember correctly (we stopped using Symantec a year ago) you have to browse for the client package when you're installing. There should be an option or a browse button during the install to specify the location of the client package.

Comment: Maybe we have slightly different installers. I have a executable installer (.exe file). When I run it, it produces the error that I described. There are no options during the installation process. Thanks though.

Comment: OK. I thought you were using the Symantec System Center to do the install. Here's a link to the release notes for 10.2 on Vista:

http://service1.symantec.com/support/ent-security.nsf/docid/2007080911252448

And here's a link for the installer for version 10.2 on Vista:

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/downloads.jsp?pid=51852

Maybe these will help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you find and run nonav249.exe and still get the error?  I have found some installs of the retail package do not fully uninstall and leave some well hidden registry items.  NONAV has ripped them out for me in the past.  Tool is available from Symantec support.  Noticed that SAV 10.2.3.3000 just released recently.

Comment: I ran the Norton Removal Tool (linked in the question) - is that different from NONAV249.exe? This information might be useful as well: information http://serverfault.com/questions/20927 I think my problem is that I have 64-bit Vista, but I don't have the 64-bit NAV installer.

Comment: nonav249.exe is a different app as far as I know. There is alos a mnaula removal instruction at the Symantec support site. The installer will usually report the issue with 32bit vs 64 bit.  Something about unsupported, don't have exact error.  I have alos had occasions where I had to copy the install folder to the local drive and then run the MSI and not the setup.exe. Odd, but it worked. Do you have a current license with Symantec so you can download latest install CD

Answer (score 0):

It could be that I have a NAV installer for 32-bit Windows Vista, but I am running 64-bit Windows Vista. Should the 32-bit version run on 64-bit Windows?